# How to Dynamically set the attributes of a component, from users input?

Tags: reactjs

Set the attributes of a input field or any component by taking input from the user dynamically?

I would like to know if there is any way, where I would give user an option to choose a component from the list of components i would mention, and allow him to customize the components attributes. For example if the user chooses a Input component, he must be able to set the attributes of that particular component, like "required", "type", "placeholder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by passing all attributes you want as props to the child component.

You should also add them to state of parent component with change handler.

Each time the user change something of the attributes, the state should update.

As the state updates, the new state will pass as props to child Component and it'll update.

I made a simple example to input: You can change its placeholder, minLength, and requierd.

[Check This Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-smoke-kpgj2)

Answer (score 1):

in the render, method you can do something like this

```
render() {

    // change the name and values base on your user input
    userInputtedAttribName = "placeholder";
    userInputtedAttribValue = "the placeholder";

    // the object to contain your user defined attribute name and values    
    const dynamicAttributes = {
        [userInputtedAttribName]: userInputtedAttribValue
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" {...dynamicAttributes}></input>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the spread operator, **{...dynamicAttributes}**, will build the attributes and their values dynamically

Comment: As the user must give the input or he have to configure the Attributes of the components from UI, is there some other way I can achieve that without using forms to take the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not even what you're looking for, but I made a medium-sized prototype that can show you how to create `Components` (input, button, textarea), dynamically.

It's like filling out a form. Choose a type of component you want to make from the select-list. Then define the attributes you want in the proceeding textboxes. Once you're done adding all the attributes, hit Generate to render your customized component.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-component-generator-mhuh5

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Input from "./Input";
import Button from "./Button";
import TextArea from "./TextArea";

import "./styles.css";

class ComponentGenerator extends React.Component {
  state = {
    componentInProgress: null,
    customizeMode: false,
    attributeName: "",
    attributeSetting: "",
    boolean: false,
    builtComponents: []
  };

  handleSelection = e => {
    this.setState({
      componentInProgress: { componentType: e.target.value },
      customizeMode: true
    });
  };

  createOptions = () => {
    const { customizeMode, componentInProgress } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Choose a Component:</h4>
        <select
          onChange={this.handleSelection}
          value={!customizeMode ? "Select" : componentInProgress.componentType}
        >
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Input</option>
          <option>TextArea</option>
          <option>Button</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    const {
      attributeName,
      attributeSetting,
      boolean,
      componentInProgress
    } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();

    let componentCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(componentInProgress));

    componentCopy.props = {
      ...componentCopy.props,
      [attributeName]: boolean ? boolean : attributeSetting
    };

    this.setState({
      componentInProgress: componentCopy,
      attributeName: "",
      attributeSetting: "",
      boolean: false
    });
  };

  setBoolean = boolean => {
    this.setState({
      boolean: boolean
    });
  };

  generateComponent = () => {
    const { componentInProgress, builtComponents } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      componentInProgress: null,
      customizeMode: false,
      builtComponents: [...builtComponents, componentInProgress]
    });
  };

  defineComponentAttributes = () => {
    const {
      componentInProgress,
      attributeName,
      attributeSetting,
      boolean
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>
          Customizing:{" "}
          <span className="highlight">{componentInProgress.componentType}</span>
        </h4>

        {/*Render form */}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
          <label>Attribute: </label>
          <input
            className="form-group"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            value={attributeName}
            name="attributeName"
            placeholder="Choose attribute (type)"
          />
          <label>Definition: </label>
          <input
            className="form-group"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            value={attributeSetting}
            name="attributeSetting"
            placeholder="Define attribute (text)"
          />
          <label>This is a Boolean type: </label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="boolean"
            onChange={() => this.setBoolean(true)}
          />
          True
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="boolean"
            checked={boolean === false}
            onChange={() => this.setBoolean(false)}
          />
          False
          <button className="form-group" type="submit">
            Add
          </button>
        </form>

        {/*Create List of attributes */}
        {componentInProgress.props && (
          <div>
            <h4>Defined Attributes:</h4>
            {Object.entries(componentInProgress.props).map(
              ([propName, propValue]) => {
                return (
                  <div key={propName}>
                    <span>{propName}: </span>
                    <span>{propValue + ""}</span>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            )}
          </div>
        )}

        <div>
          <h4>Click to finish and generate:</h4>
          <button onClick={this.generateComponent}>Generate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderComponents = () => {
    const { builtComponents } = this.state;
    return builtComponents.map((component, index) => {
      let renderedComponent = () => {
        switch (component.componentType) {
          case "Input":
            return <Input {...component.props} />;
          case "Button":
            return <Button {...component.props} />;
          case "TextArea":
            return <TextArea {...component.props} />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      };

      return (
        <div key={index} className="componentSection">
          <h4>{component.componentType}</h4>
          {renderedComponent()}
          <div>
            <p>Attributes: </p>
            {Object.entries(component.props).map(([propName, propValue]) => {
              return (
                <div key={propName}>
                  <span>{propName}: </span>
                  <span>{propValue + ""}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { customizeMode } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createOptions()}
        {customizeMode && this.defineComponentAttributes()}
        <div className="components">{this.renderComponents()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentGenerator />, rootElement);
```